# GIDSignInButton - Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, google-signin

I keep getting a **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**  error when clicking on a view using the **GIDSignInBUtton** class. Has anyone had this problem before or have experience with the Google Sign In API that could help me?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Google
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
// [START appdelegate_interfaces]
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    // [END appdelegate_interfaces]
    var window: UIWindow?

    // [START didfinishlaunching]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }
    // [END didfinishlaunching]
    // [START openurl]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                 annotation: annotation)
    }
    // [END openurl]
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    // [START signin_handler]
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(fullName)"])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
    // [END signin_handler]
    // [START disconnect_handler]
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnected."])
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END disconnect_handler]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

After hours of exploring source files and .plist files, I found that I mistakenly put CLIENT_ID from GoogleService-Info.plist instead of REVERSED_CLIENT_ID inside URL Types.

- TARGET(Right click on your project)
- Info
- URL Types (Entered REVERSED_CLIENT_ID instead of CLIENT_ID)

And it worked.
Hope this will help.